# Taking part of ajax response with jQuery.filter fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The code below is not working. It receives html with appropriate div with `class="filtered_entries_box"`. The problem is filtering.

```
$.ajax({
    "url" : "start.php",
    "type" : "POST",
    "data" : "action=entries",
    "dataType" : "html",
    "success" : function(data) {
        var filtered_entries_box = $($(data).filter(".filtered_entries_box")[0]).html();
        $(".filtered_entries_box").html(filtered_entries_box);
    }
});
```

I have tried it with another div, and it worked. The only difference between them is that second one is much closer to `<body>`, so maybe filter can not work with a deep DOM objects?

```
....
"success" : function(data) {
    var contentDiv = $($(data).filter(".container")[0]).html();
    $(".container").html(contentDiv);
}
....
```

My html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top_bar">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="new_entry_box">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="filtered_entries_box">
    ...
```

Can filter work with that or not? Appreciate any advices.

Comment: You need to .find it since it's a child of container rather than a sibling.

Comment: Does .filter works only with a siblings? Thanks, .find worked well :)

Comment: Yes, filter just filters the currently selected elements, which in your case are the top level elements in the html returned.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I'll try to rewrite all my ajax calls with .find now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var html = $('.filtered_entries_box', data).html();
```